# Redirect old URL to new URL by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change URL format from :

```
https://example.com/modules/news/article.php?storyid=224039
```

to :

```
https://example.com/news/224039
```

Any one can help to write true .htaccess codes?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) /modules/news/article.php?storyid=$1 [NC,L]
```

The NC flag is for No Case, if you want case insensitivity. If not, remove this flag.  The L is the Last flag, meaning it would be the last rule parsed in the given rewrite instance so further rewrites aren't used. This is a bit counterintuitive in the sense that Apache will re-read all the rules all over again from the beginning anyways after the rewrite to make sure it doesn't have to rewrite again, and is a gotcha for many people regarding infinite rewrite loops... Probably can also omit the L flag altogether, but is more expressive.

The RewriteEngine On can be omitted in Apache configurations that enable this in the httpd.conf file. It is best practice to put it on again before assuming the engine is on. The rewrite base `/` probably can be omitted, depends on how you write your RewriteRule. Finally the RewriteRule uses a regular expression on the left, the parenthesis stores the match, the brackets define a character list, 0-9 is the valid characters, could also use `\d` instead, the `+` means match 1 or more times. The expression on the right is what to replace it with. The leading slash can probably be omitted. Also note that due to the presence of a querystring on the right side, if a querystring was present on the left side, it will be discarded. If you want to merge query strings, use the `QSA` flag meaning querystring append, and then it will merge querystrings when adding your storyid. Finally the `$1` means use the first match that was captured with parenthesis on the left.

Comment: The pattern should be `^/?news/(\d+)$` and the `NC` flag is not required. Also typically the `END` flag should be preferred to the old `L` flag.